# How can I reduce the size of doughnut chart and fixed the doughnut size

Tags: javascript, chart.js, salesforce, lwc, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a doughnut chart built using chart js. I want a fixed-size of doughnut chart no matter how much data it has. check the image how bad it is looking It has 371 legends. How can I fix the size of the doughnut chart?

[Doughnut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Eee.png)

Comment: You should provide code examples in your question

Answer (score 2):

You can try two steps: `height` at HTML/CSS and `aspectRation` at JS.

The `height` will control de DIV where the graphic is, which may solve your issue. Also, please look for no missing DIV or something similar.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="graphicID" style="height:50vh;"></canvas>
</div>
```

After that you may notice the graphic size is too small, not filling all DIV space available. For this you will need review the `aspectRation`, which control the size of the graphic within the DIV. Default for `doughnut` is 1, but for me 1.4 was a good approach.

```
const config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
        aspectRatio: 1.4,
    }
};
```

For additional information please check https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html

Comment: underrated answer! aspectRatio did it for me. cheers!